# How to calculate the red lines on the following triangle?

Tags: sequences-and-series, triangles

How can I calculate the length of the red lines that are marked on this triangle

[image: Triangle problem]

All the information I have is that $a$ = 1 m and that $\alpha=60^\circ$.

Comment: Are the lines $b_1,b_2...$ perpendicular to the base of the triangle?

Comment: Is that symbol of angle with a dot in it the same as "Straight angle"?  If you could upload a diagram it will help a lot (the site you linked isn't supported here)

Comment: @tatan The text just says "Calculate the length of the red marked lines"

Comment: @DonAntonio I'll upload the picture on a different website now.

Comment: @DonAntonio and yes the dot means that it is a straight angle.

Comment: Use the fact that in the largest right triangle, you have $\dfrac{b_1}{a}=\sin(\alpha) \iff b_1=a \sin(\alpha)$, in the second to largest, you again multiply by $\sin(\alpha)$ etc...  The general answer is $b_k=a sin(\alpha)^{2k-1}$. Do you see why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have $b_1=a \sin(\alpha)$
Then you can see that the right angle triangle are similar, with $\alpha$ as an angle. That yields: $\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_{n} \cos(\alpha)}=\cos(\alpha)$ and therefore $b_{n+1}=b_n \cos^2(\alpha)$
So $b_2=a \sin(\alpha) \cos^2(\alpha)$
So $b_3=a \sin(\alpha) \cos^4(\alpha)$
So $b_4=a \sin(\alpha) \cos^6(\alpha)$
(assuming the . angle is 90 degrees)
And more generally $b_n=a \sin(\alpha) \cos^{2(n-1)}(\alpha)$